# Maximum and minimum output at DAmp

Tags: amplifier

What is the maximum and minimum output on the Vout in differential amplifier circuit?
Is it Vcc and Vcc-R*I0?
And when does differential amplifier enter saturation?[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but if we have to guess what your schematic looks like then you'll have to guess what our answers would look like.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you would know the differential amplifier base circuit, adding a picture.

Comment: That's OK. There are many. I assumed you were asking about an op-amp circuit so your photo makes it clear what you are talking about. Since this is a homework question you need to show some effort or else the question will be closed. Show how far you got and where you are stuck.

Comment: Well it's not a homework question, I have an exam. Here's what I think: when T2 is off, output on Vc1 is Vcc-RcI0, and when T1 is off, output on Vc1 is Vcc

Comment: When we say "homework" question we mean a question of the type that often gets asked as homework. It doesn't matter if it's actually homework, an exam, a practice exam, or some other kind of exercise, we still consider it "homework".

Comment: Ok, sorry, I've answered in a comment what I think it is.